# Compiling a test file in a different folder in the same directory

Tags: java, selenium, compilation

I have a java file and a test file Triangle.java and TriangleTest.java

I have a directory as follows : C:\Users\A\Desktop\NewPrograms

The structure looks something like --

class

test

files

source

completed

The source file is inside the source folder and the test file is inside the test folder and the .class file is in the class folder

I want to compile the test file, I have added the jars - **selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-6,selenium-java-4.0.0-alpha-6,hamcrest-2.2 and junit-4.13.1**

into the test folder and using -

**javac --release 8 -cp "junit-4.13.1.jar;selenium-java-4.0.0-alpha-6.jar;selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-6.jar;." TriangleTest.java**

I try to compile it but I find that it will not compile unless the source file and class file is in the same folder as the test file but I cannot put them in the same folder so **is there a way or a sequence of commands that can allow me to run the tests without having source and class files in the same folder as the test file?**

Answer (score 0):

Just add folder `class` to the class-path, so that javac can find the class under test. Of course, you need to compile the class under test first.

But (big but): it's not advisable to compile files manually using javac. Instead use some build-tool like Maven or Graven. These tools support testing, too. Also consider to use some IDE.